# Be all out of steam

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Is the idiom ***all out of steam*** commonly used in casual American speech? Is it common to hear someone saying ***I'm all out of steam***, I can't walk another step?

Otherwise, what do we say if someone is totally exhausted and can not move?

Comment: 'ready to drop', 'plumb tuckered', 'all in' ....

Comment: It was once common, but it's losing currency, since steam power has become pretty rare.  Back when steam engines were common it would have had a much more tangible meaning.

Comment: Is **I'm plumb tuckered** commonly used in casual speech?

Comment: @user385505, "plumb tuckered" strikes me as a product of the American South, where it is heard frequently—in New England, not so much.

Comment: "Plumb tuckered" is generally regarded as "rural" speech in the US.

Comment: There are ***so*** many ways to say it that to tag one as common is hard.  They’re all used commonly, but that might not equate to frequently.  I’m sure I hear “i ran out of steam” at least 5 times a year.  I may hear “I’m all tuckered out” twice a year.  I may hear “I’m pooped” 2-3 times a year. But all of those are common expressions.  Now, “My dogs are barkin’” is a more humorous way of saying my feet are aching which I’ve only heard once “in the wild” but now my family says quite often because we thought it was funny the first time we heard it.

Answer (score 1):

The expression is:

***[to run out of steam](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/inglese/to-run-out-of-steam)***

> If you run out of steam, you stop doing something because you have no more energy or enthusiasm left.
> (informal)
>
> - I decided to paint the bathroom ceiling but ran out of steam halfway through.

(Collins)

Comment: Is the expression commonly used in casual day-to-day speech? Do we hear it frequently?

Comment: Rather than "I ran out of steam," @user385505, I am more accustomed to hearing people speak of a project or a program running out of steam. Perhaps I'm making too fine a distinction, but to answer your question, I hear it only occasionally. That being said, it is common enough that I am not surprised or taken aback when I do.

Comment: @user385505: This is a very common idiom, in British English at least. user121863's example sounds perfectly normal to me. And "all out of steam" is a natural variant.